# Named index offsets in Python list?

Tags: python

Is there a good Pythonic way to name index offsets within a list?

I have a list of lists, each of which represents an account that my script will setup:

```
#                        un       pw        doit   admin
ExtraAccounts       = [["Fred", "fredpw1",  True,  False],
                       ["Jane", "ibjane",   True,  True],
                       ["Wen",  "35syzwen", False, True],
                      ]
```

So username "Fred" will be setup with password "fredpw1", and won't be an admin. Etc.

Index [0] of each sublist is the username, [1] the password, [3] is whether the account is an admin or not.

This leads to code like this:

```
for acct in ExtraAccounts:
    if acct[2]:
        setupAccount(acct[0], acct[1], acct[3])
```

It's difficult to read, because it's far from obvious what acct[0], acct[1], acct[2], etc. represent.

I thought of using named tuples, but I also need to change the contents of the list in the program, like this:

```
for acct in ExtraAccounts:
        acct[2] = aComplicatedFunction(acct[0])
```

So I rejected using named tuples, because they're immutable.

I came up with this as a workaround:

```
User  = 0 # index offsets
Pass  = 1
Doit  = 2
Admin = 3
#                        un       pw        doit   admin
ExtraAccounts       = [["Fred", "fredpw1",  True,  False],
                       ["Jane", "ibjane",   True,  True],
                       ["Wen",  "35syzwen", False, True],
                      ]

for acct in ExtraAccounts:
    acct[Doit] = aComplicatedFunction(acct[User])

for acct in ExtraAccounts:
    if acct[Doit]:
        setupAccount(acct[User], acct[Pass], acct[Admin])
```

...but I'm pretty sure that's not the "right way" to do this.

What is the better way?

Comment: Use `namedtuple`.

Comment: @Daniel. I failed to mention that I have to change the contents of ExtraAccounts programmatically. Tuples are immutable.

Comment: @nerdfever.com then this would be a good case for a class, surely?

Comment: ~~@Daniel 's answer works.~~ ~~But~~If you want big data you should take a look at simple Dataframes with `Pandas`. It makes using lists like these very practical especially if they get big.

Comment: List of dictionaries can help you: `[{"User":"Fred", "Pass":"fredpw1", "Doit":True,  "Admin ":False}, ...]`

Comment: What you are dong is not wrong. Giving names to the indices is certainly better than magic numbers. Remember that you can assign names to `slice` objects if you need ranges of indices. I second zivos recommendation to look into the `pandas` library for these kinds of tasks.

Comment: @timgeb Isn't Pandas overkill for this? I only have a dozen or so accounts in the list. Hardly "big data".

Comment: @nerdfever.com: Yes, Pandas is probably both inappropriate and overkill for this.

Comment: @nerdfever.com maybe for your small scale program. But in general, for working with indexed rows, it's definitely worth knowing.

Comment: @nerdfever.com, please read my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a class?

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, username, password, doit, admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.doit = doit
        self.admin = admin


extra_accounts = [
    #        un       pw        doit   admin
    Account("Fred", "fredpw1",  True,  False),
    Account("Jane", "ibjane",   True,  True),
    Account("Wen",  "35syzwen", False, True),
]

for acct in extra_accounts:
    acct.doit = a_complicated_function(acct.username)

for acct in extra_accounts:
    if acct.doit:
        setup_account(acct.username, acct.password, acct.admin)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Best answer so far - the only one that doesn't repeat 'user', 'pw', etc. in every line of code (redundantly). Still, it seems like a lot of overhead to create the class just for this. Hard to believe there's no more direct solution in Python.

Comment: @nerdfever.com The fact that you have to write the constructor this way (without using something like [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html)) is unfortunate, but apart from that, this is exactly what classes are for.

Comment: @nerdfever.com if you prefer not to create a class, you can always use `recordtype`. please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would have used `namedtuple` but since your requirement is mutable, You can use `dict()` to create dictionary with `User` as key and `dict` as values for other variables. I personally find it easy to read,

[image]

**Code,**

```
userData = {"Fred": {"pw": "passw", "doit" : False, "admin": False}}


# Get password,
print(userData["Fred"]["pw"])

# admin?
print(userData["Fred"]["admin"])
```

Or if you want much cleaner code, you can use `recordtype`

`recordtype` provides a factory function, named `recordtype.recordtype`. It is similar to `collections.namedtuple`, with the following differences:

- recordtype instances are mutable.
- recordtype supports per-field default values.
- recordtype supports an optional default value, to be used by all fields do not have an explicit default value.

Something like,

```
from recordtype import recordtype

account_data = recordtype('Account', 'user pw doit admin')
accounts = [
    account_data("Fred", "fredpw1",  True,  False),
    account_data("Jane", "ibjane",   True,  True),
    account_data("Wen",  "35syzwen", False, True),
   ]

for account in accounts:
    # change password
    account.pw = "new password"
```

Note: You'd need to install it manually `pip install recordtype`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `dict`.

```
extra_accounts = [
    {'user': 'Fred', 'pw': 'fredpw1', 'doit': True, 'admin': False},
    {'user': 'Jane', 'pw': 'ibjane', 'doit': True, 'admin': True},
    {'user': 'Wen', 'pw': '35syzwen', 'doit': False, 'admin': True},
]

for acct in extra_accounts:
    if acct['doit']:
        setup_account(acct['user'], acct['pass'], acct['admin'])
```

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't recommend Pandas if all you want to do is  keep data around for system maintenance